# eDrawings Displays Text Differently Than Spinfire

Tags: cad, drawings

I am generating a very simple DXF file with the [netDXF](https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf) library. The DXF is a polyine box with text in the middle. When I open the file in SpinFire and DWG Trueview the text is centered (image with H aligned center). However, when I open it in eDrawings the text is way off (image with H off center).

Does anyone know what could cause this? I wonder if I am missing something in the header or what could cause these viewers to show the same file differently. My best guess is that eDrawings does not respect the alignment property. Any insight is greatly appreciated.
[image: SpinFire]
[image: eDrawings]

Comment: Please add screenshots? And perhaps even some link to the file if it's not confidential

Comment: Thanks Jonathan I added screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be just a quirk of eDrawings where it prefers the MText object. Discussion [here](https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf/discussions/262).